# Como chamar uma JFrame de outra JFrame com classes diferentes

Tags: java, swing, jframe

Estou criando um joguinho de pedra papel e tesoura e gostaria de saber como eu chamo uma `JFrame` de outra `JFrame`, só que de classes diferentes. Ou talvez deveria fazer em métodos diferentes? Eu tentei fazer aqui mas sempre dava erro. Acho que eu não tava conseguindo chamar corretamente.

Vou postar os códigos abaixo:

Principal:

```
public class Principal {

private JFrame frame;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Principal window = new Principal();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the application.
 */
public Principal() {
    initialize();
}

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */
private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JLabel lblPedraPapelOu = new JLabel("Pedra Papel ou Tesoura!");
    lblPedraPapelOu.setFont(new Font("Comic Sans MS", Font.BOLD, 26));

    JLabel label = new JLabel("");
    label.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\nelio\\workspace\\PedraPapelOuTesoura\\Imagens\\pedra-papel-tesoura-final.png"));

    JButton btnIniciar = new JButton("Iniciar");
    btnIniciar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            //AQUI!

        }
    });
    btnIniciar.setForeground(new Color(0, 204, 0));
    btnIniciar.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 16));

    JButton btnSair = new JButton("Sair");
    btnSair.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });
    btnSair.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 16));
    GroupLayout groupLayout = new GroupLayout(frame.getContentPane());
    groupLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
        groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(Alignment.TRAILING, groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(69)
                .addComponent(lblPedraPapelOu, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGap(88))
            .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                    .addGroup(Alignment.LEADING, groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(79)
                        .addComponent(btnIniciar)
                        .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(btnSair))
                    .addGroup(Alignment.LEADING, groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(61)
                        .addComponent(label)))
                .addContainerGap(73, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    groupLayout.setVerticalGroup(
        groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(lblPedraPapelOu, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(label)
                .addGap(44)
                .addGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(btnIniciar)
                    .addComponent(btnSair))
                .addGap(29))
    );
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(groupLayout);
}
}
```

A tela que eu gostaria de chamar:

```
public class TelaJogo {

JFrame tela;
    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    TelaJogo window = new TelaJogo();
                    window.tela.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public TelaJogo() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the tela.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        tela = new JFrame();
        tela.setBounds(100, 100, 328, 298);
        tela.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JButton btnPedra = new JButton("Pedra");
        btnPedra.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 16));

        JButton btnPapel = new JButton("Papel");
        btnPapel.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 16));

        JButton btnTesoura = new JButton("Tesoura");
        btnTesoura.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 16));

        JLabel lblFaaSuaEscolha = new JLabel("Fa\u00E7a sua escolha:");
        lblFaaSuaEscolha.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 16));

        JLabel lblJogador = new JLabel("Jogador");
        lblJogador.setForeground(new Color(0, 128, 0));
        lblJogador.setFont(new Font("Copperplate Gothic Bold", Font.BOLD, 18));

        JLabel lblIa = new JLabel("I.A");
        lblIa.setForeground(new Color(255, 0, 0));
        lblIa.setFont(new Font("Copperplate Gothic Bold", Font.BOLD, 28));
        GroupLayout groupLayout = new GroupLayout(tela.getContentPane());
        groupLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
            groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGap(134)
                            .addComponent(lblIa, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 63, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGap(90)
                            .addComponent(lblFaaSuaEscolha))
                        .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addContainerGap()
                            .addComponent(btnPedra)
                            .addGap(9)
                            .addGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                                .addComponent(lblJogador)
                                .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                                    .addComponent(btnPapel)
                                    .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                    .addComponent(btnTesoura, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 117, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))))
                    .addContainerGap(10, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        groupLayout.setVerticalGroup(
            groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.TRAILING)
                .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap()
                    .addComponent(lblIa, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 21, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 118, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(lblFaaSuaEscolha)
                    .addGap(18)
                    .addGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(btnPedra)
                        .addComponent(btnPapel)
                        .addComponent(btnTesoura))
                    .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                    .addComponent(lblJogador)
                    .addGap(10))
        );
        tela.getContentPane().setLayout(groupLayout);
    }

}
```

(Todos os pacotes incluidos, so tirei pra postar aqui pra ficar mais facil pra ver)

Botei um `//AQUI` no principal pra acharem o `actionperformed` que estou trabalhando.

Comment: Teria como você postar o stack trace?

Comment: Porque não usa JDialog ao inves de varias frames?

Answer (score 1):

Uma das soluções seria você usar [`JDialog`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html), cuja finalidade é justamente essa, quando se precisa de mais de uma janela. A diferença é que ela será dependente do seu Frame principal(mesmo sendo uma janela também), e tem a opção de ser [modal](http://www.guj.com.br/t/modal-em-java-o-que-e-isso/86389/2).

Outra coisa, normalmente quando se trabalha com classes que representam telas, é mais recomendado que você estenda de `JFrame`(ou outra classe de frame), assim você aproveita funcionalidades já escritas na classe, sem ter que ficar criando método pra encapsular sua variável que representa o `JFrame`.

Modifiquei sua classe um pouco, e veja como ficou, basta aplicar a lógica do seu jogo.

**Classe Principal:**

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment;
import javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement;

public class Principal{

    private JFrame frame;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Principal window = new Principal();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public Principal() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JLabel lblPedraPapelOu = new JLabel("Pedra Papel ou Tesoura!");
        lblPedraPapelOu.setFont(new Font("Comic Sans MS", Font.BOLD, 26));

        JLabel label = new JLabel("");
        label.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\nelio\\workspace\\PedraPapelOuTesoura\\Imagens\\pedra-papel-tesoura-final.png"));

        JButton btnIniciar = new JButton("Iniciar");
        btnIniciar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                //a chamada da tela modal  
                TelaJogo telaJogo = new TelaJogo(frame, true);
                telaJogo.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        btnIniciar.setForeground(new Color(0, 204, 0));
        btnIniciar.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 16));

        JButton btnSair = new JButton("Sair");
        btnSair.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        btnSair.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 16));
        GroupLayout groupLayout = new GroupLayout(frame.getContentPane());
        groupLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
                groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(Alignment.TRAILING, groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(69)
                        .addComponent(lblPedraPapelOu, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addGap(88))
                .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                                .addGroup(Alignment.LEADING, groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                                        .addGap(79)
                                        .addComponent(btnIniciar)
                                        .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                        .addComponent(btnSair))
                                .addGroup(Alignment.LEADING, groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                                        .addGap(61)
                                        .addComponent(label)))
                        .addContainerGap(73, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        groupLayout.setVerticalGroup(
                groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addContainerGap()
                        .addComponent(lblPedraPapelOu, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(label)
                        .addGap(44)
                        .addGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.BASELINE)
                                .addComponent(btnIniciar)
                                .addComponent(btnSair))
                        .addGap(29))
        );
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(groupLayout);
    }
}
```

**Classe TelaJogo:**

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment;
import javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement;

public class TelaJogo extends JDialog{

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public TelaJogo(Frame owner, boolean isModal) {
        super(owner, isModal);
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the tela.
     */
    private void initialize() {

        this.setBounds(100, 100, 328, 298);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        JButton btnPedra = new JButton("Pedra");
        btnPedra.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 16));

        JButton btnPapel = new JButton("Papel");
        btnPapel.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 16));

        JButton btnTesoura = new JButton("Tesoura");
        btnTesoura.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 16));

        JLabel lblFaaSuaEscolha = new JLabel("Fa\u00E7a sua escolha:");
        lblFaaSuaEscolha.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 16));

        JLabel lblJogador = new JLabel("Jogador");
        lblJogador.setForeground(new Color(0, 128, 0));
        lblJogador.setFont(new Font("Copperplate Gothic Bold", Font.BOLD, 18));

        JLabel lblIa = new JLabel("I.A");
        lblIa.setForeground(new Color(255, 0, 0));
        lblIa.setFont(new Font("Copperplate Gothic Bold", Font.BOLD, 28));
        GroupLayout groupLayout = new GroupLayout(this.getContentPane());
        groupLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
            groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGap(134)
                            .addComponent(lblIa, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 63, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGap(90)
                            .addComponent(lblFaaSuaEscolha))
                        .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addContainerGap()
                            .addComponent(btnPedra)
                            .addGap(9)
                            .addGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                                .addComponent(lblJogador)
                                .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                                    .addComponent(btnPapel)
                                    .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                    .addComponent(btnTesoura, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 117, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))))
                    .addContainerGap(10, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        groupLayout.setVerticalGroup(
            groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.TRAILING)
                .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap()
                    .addComponent(lblIa, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 21, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 118, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(lblFaaSuaEscolha)
                    .addGap(18)
                    .addGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(btnPedra)
                        .addComponent(btnPapel)
                        .addComponent(btnTesoura))
                    .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                    .addComponent(lblJogador)
                    .addGap(10))
        );
        this.getContentPane().setLayout(groupLayout);
    }

}
```

Dessa forma, ao se clicar no `btnIniciar` da classe principal, será exibida a tela do seu jogo. Caso queira que a tela principal fique escondida quando a tela do jogo estiver aberta, basta modificar dentro do `actionPerformed`:

```
@Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                //a chamada da tela modal  
                frame.setVisible(false);
                TelaJogo telaJogo = new TelaJogo(frame, true);
                telaJogo.setVisible(true);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
```

A classe principal pode ser melhorada, mas para não alterar demais seu código, apenas adaptei a classe `TelaJogo`.