# Retornar informações da linha da jtable após seleção

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Tenho uma aplicação com 2 JFrames..

1º JFrame: Uma tela com um botão de pesquisa e JTextField

2º JFrame: Uma JTable com as informações do BD.

Quando clico no botão de pesquisa no 1º Frame abre a `JTable` com as informações do BD tudo certo.

Queria fazer que, ao clicar em uma linha da `JTable` , mostrasse as informações no 1º Frame e fechasse a JTable como consequência do clique.

Comment: Ãdicione o código do que você fez até agora.

Comment: Você criou um abstractTableModel ou esta usando o Default?

Answer (score 1):

Outra alternativa é usar um evento que monitora seleções feitas na tabela:

```
suaTable.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener(){

    @Override
    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {

        ListSelectionModel lsm = (ListSelectionModel) e.getSource();

        if(!lsm.isSelectionEmpty()){

        //aqui você insere a ação que quer fazer quando
        //uma linha for selecionada ou uma seleção for
        //alterada na tabela
        }
    }
}
```

E não esqueça de converter o indice da tabela para o do model, para evitar problemas de `indexofboundException` caso insira filtros na tabela.

```
int rowSel = suaTable.getSelectedRow();//pega o indice da linha na tabela
int indexRowModel = suaTable.getRowSorter().convertRowIndexToModel(rowSel);//converte pro indice do model
```

Caso não tenha um método que retorne um objeto do seu model, você pode usar o método `getValueAt(indexRow, indexColumn)` para pegar os valores de cada coluna da linha e popular seu objeto. O método ficaria mais um menos assim:

```
suaTable.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {

    @Override
    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {

        ListSelectionModel lsm = (ListSelectionModel) e.getSource();

        if(!lsm.isSelectionEmpty()){

          int rowSel = suaTable.getSelectedRow();//pega o indice da linha na tabela
          int indexRowModel = suaTable.getRowSorter().convertRowIndexToModel(rowSel);//converte pro indice do model
          //aqui você adapta conforme sua tabela e seu objeto,
          //alterando o indice da coluna
          seuTable.getModel().getValueAt(indexRowModel, indiceDaColuna);
        }               
    }
});
```

Outra dica seria usar `JDialog` para telas secundarias da sua aplicação, e utilizar `JFrame` apenas na principal, desta forma você consegue controlar a visibilidade e resgatar facilmente informações entre essas janelas, mesmo após de ter dado `dispose` nas janelas filhas. [**Neste link**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) você obtém informações sobre o uso de `JDialogs`, seu uso é bastante parecido com as `JFrames`, com a adição de torná-la uma [**janela modal**](http://www.guj.com.br/t/modal-em-java-o-que-e-isso/86389/2).

[**Nesta pergunta**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/137711/pegar-linha-da-jtable-ap%C3%B3s-filtrar-dados/137744#137744) tem um exemplo parecido com o seu.

---

Outras referencias:

[Atualizar uma Jtable que está numa JFrame a partir de um JDialog](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/111258/atualizar-uma-jtable-que-est%C3%A1-numa-jframe-a-partir-de-um-jdialog/111408#111408)

[Como chamar uma JFrame de outra JFrame com classes diferentes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/118172/como-chamar-uma-jframe-de-outra-jframe-com-classes-diferentes/118192#118192)

Answer (score 0):

Se voce esta usando o AbstractTableModel baseado na classe... voce primeiro deve ao chamar a segunda tela, criar uma metodo na segunda tela que receba da onde ela veio.
tipo, tem o JFrame1 que abre o JFrame2, quando voce chamar o JFrame2, voce tambem deve chamar um metodo que voce deve criar no JFrame dois...
Exemplo.
No JFrame 2 deve possuir

```
 JFrame1 JFrame1;
/* Construtor*/
public JFrame2() {
 }
public void setTelaPai(JFrame1 jframe1) {
this.JFrame1 = jframe1 ;
}
```

Com isso quando voce for chamar o JFrame2, voce deve chamar o metodo

```
JFrame2 jframe2 = new JFrame2();
jframe2.setVisible(true);
jframe2.setTelaPai(this);
```

Agora no segundo frame, ele já sebe para onde voltar, pois já sabe qual é o seu pai.  Agora vá no evento click do JTable... E faça assim

```
        private void jTable1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
  if (evt.getClickCount() == 2) {
     int linSelect = jTable1.getSelectedRow();
  if(linSelect!=-1){

        SeUsuarios usuarios = (SeUsuarios) abstractTableUsuario.getUsuario(linSelect);

        JFrame1.usuariosTela(usuarios);
        setVisible(false); 
     } else{
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Selecione uma linha");
     }  
}
}
```

Esse método usuariosTela é um metodo que recebe o objeto usuário, e preenche a tela, ele é usado porque uma segunda tela nao conseguie acessar os campos da outra, enta por isso tem que criar um metodo publico na propria tela para ser chamado em outra. Espero ter ajudado...